# Is there a simpler way to write this query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have three tables. Categories, topics, and posts. Each topic has a foreign key that references the category that it's under. Each post has a foreign key that references the topic that it's under.

The purpose of this query is to basically be the front page query.  I want each category along with the number of topics and number of posts in each category.  This is the query I have, and it works.  Is this the simplest way of going about it?

```
SELECT      c.*,
            COUNT(t.idCategory) AS tCount,
            p.pCount
FROM        categories AS c
  LEFT JOIN topics AS t
  ON        c.id = t.idCategory
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT      t.idCategory,
                         COUNT(p2.idTopic) AS pCount
             FROM        topics AS t
               LEFT JOIN posts AS p2
               ON        t.id = p2.idTopic
             GROUP BY    t.idCategory) AS p
  ON         c.id = p.idCategory
GROUP BY     t.idCategory
ORDER BY     c.id
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much about as simple as it gets unless you store the counts directly inside the parent tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking of simplicity I guess this could be an answer:

```
Select 
      c.*,
      (Select count(*) from topic t where c.id = t.idCategory) as tCount,
      (Select count(*) from posts p join topics t2 on t2.id = p.idTopic where c.id = t2.idCategory) as pCount
From categories c
```

Comment: That works Sam, and is easier to understand. Can you tell me how the topic count is updated for each category?  The portion c.id=t2.idCategory seems that it would just match once and then keep the same count for each row.  Does it iterate through each category and then run that query matching each category with the topics?

Comment: Yes, subqueries will be executed per each row of the master query(conceptually at least). So imagine you are writing the select statement to count the topics of an specific category.

Answer (score 0):

You can put together the topics and posts inside the derived table first before joining with the categories:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    COUNT(tp.id) AS TotalTopics,
    tp.TotalPosts
FROM categories AS c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            t.id,
            t.idCategory,
            COUNT(p.id) AS TotalPosts
        FROM topics AS t 
            LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON t.id = p.idTopic
        GROUP BY    
            t.id,
            t.idCategory) AS tp ON c.id = tp.idCategory
GROUP BY 
    c.id,
    tp.TotalPosts
ORDER BY c.id
```